# Dependencies could not be resolved Error

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I try to install the extension `extension builder` to my typo3 installation, but it throws the following error:

[image]

As you see it says there are errors while trying to install, but it only shows an empty listpoint.

Even if I click on `yes` to proceed anyway it shows the same error again.
I've got the same error with another extension before (dont know which one it was). At the time i searched for an alternative, but unfortunately there is no equal alternative for the `extension builder` as far as i know. (kickstarter isn't supported in 6.2 anymore)

There are no errors in the apache error log either.

Any idea where the problem is?

My Versions for PHP and Typo3

- Typo3 Version: 6.2.9
- PHP Version: 5.4.20

If you need any more information let me know.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the issue now. The problem was that the "uploads" directory didn't have the correct rights for writing and the extensions wants to create a folder in that directory on installation.

Don't know why the problem didn't appeare in the error log, but thats another thing.